# How to send post data in big5 encoding with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, encoding, firefox-addon

I tried to develop a firefox add-on recently to handle some routines automatically.

There is some webpage composed of a lot of links, and each link points to a page which contains a form tag. When the webpage is loaded, I want to inject a script, which follows through each link in webpage and click the submit button inside.

I use $.get to get each link in the webpage, parse post data with $('form').serialize(), and click the submit button by using $.post.

The issue is that the pages I'm dealing with is big5 encoded. When jQuery loads the data, it transforms the information in the page into Unicode. And then I use $.post to send the Unicode data. But the server side only accepts data in big5 encoding.

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: this.href,
    success: function(data){
      var html = $.parseHTML(data);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('form', html).attr('action'),
        data: $('form', html).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I have no control over the server side, so the only way I can do is to modify my add-on scripts. I have googled a lot with keywords (jQuery, encoding, big5, form) and still have no results.

Can we send data in big5 via jQuery.post? Or is there other way I can do to finish my add-on?

Thank you :)

Comment: For reference, firefox provides some APIs for its extensions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter